# How can I invisible mapview view on navigationview

Tags: android, android-mapview, navigationview, mapbox-android

I am trying a navigation application demo. I use a button,a mapview and a navigation view same layout. When layout created, mapview init for getting destination point and drawing route from current location. Then when clicked on the start button, The navigationview is starting to navigate. The scenario is working fine.

But have a problem, when navigationview started to navigate, mapview view didn't go. Just map view is staying navigation view.

I added screenshots.

[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZM4A.jpg)

[Start to navigate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkhSY.jpg)

My Layout xml code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_Navigate"
    android:layout_width="410dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Start Navigate"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_viewMap"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="17"></com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_viewNavigate"
    android:layout_width="1000dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:visibility="visible"></com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationView>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And I tried everything about setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) or bringtoFront() functions but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cover your

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_viewMap"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="17"></com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

With a **FrameLayout**.

**Changes:**

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_viewMap"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="17"></com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It didn't work. The mapview always stay back navigationview. First, I have to see mapview map and to select a destination point.